# How can I create a multi module project in Eclipse/Maven - Just ONE big project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I don't normally open the `pom.xml` file and I always using the graphical user friendly interface (GUFI) in Eclipse when I create a maven project.

I'm right now reading a course where my teacher show how to create a multi module project in Intellij. The problem is that I have Eclipse.

He create a multi module project, where there is ONE big project and inside the project there are modules, e.g sub-projects with own pom.xml files.

When I create a project named `Topp` and a module named `Sopp`, it will looks like this in Eclipse.
[image]

But inside the project folder, it looks as it should do.

[image]

**Question:**

Is there a way to make it look so the module `Sopp` is inside the `Topp` project in Eclipse `Project Explorer`?

Comment: This isn't the answer you are asking for, but it's the answer you need.  Multi module projects are rather easy to setup by editing pom.xml directly.  Please read and look at the examples here https://books.sonatype.com/mvnex-book/reference/multimodule.html . The eclipse plugins should pick it up right away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your parent pom should have like this

```
 <modules>
    <module>submodule1</module>
    <module>submodule2</module>
    <module>submodule3</module>
</modules>
```

Packaging of parent should be pom.

```
<packaging>pom</packaging>
```

It will pick up itself. Refer this http://websystique.com/maven/creating-maven-multi-module-project-with-eclipse/

Comment: I have the modules like this, but still....eclipse will still show the modules outside of the project.

Answer (score 1):

You choose the downward triangle in the project explorer (on the right top corner), then you choose "Projects Presentation" and then "Hierarchical".